# The derivative of sum of vector norms

Tags: derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

This is kind of complicated for me so I have to call for your help.

Let $x,y$ be vectors of size $2\times N$, and $A,B$ matrices of size $2 \times 2$. Then let
$f$ be a function of scalar $a$:

$f(a) = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \|A e^{-aB} x_i - y_i\|_2$

where $x_i, y_i$ are the columns of $x,y$ at index i.

What is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $a$? Is it calculable analytically?

---

EDIT:

I get

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \dfrac{A B e^{-aB}x_i}{N \|A e^{-aB} x_i - y_i\|_2}$

but is it actually correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's use a notation wherein an uppercase letter denotes a matrix, lowercase a vector, and a Greek letter a scalar, and rename some of the problem variables $\,(a,f,x,y)\to(\a,\phi,X,Y)$.

Using $e_k\in\bbR n$ to denote the standard basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
X &= \m{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n}  &\qiq x_k=Xe_k \\
Y &= \m{\,y_1&\,y_2&\ldots&y_n} &\qiq y_k=Ye_k \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
E &= e^{-\a B} &\qiq dE = -EB\;d\a \\
Z &= AEX-Y &\qiq \c{dZ} = A\,dE\,X = \c{-AEBX\;d\a} \\
M &= Z^TZ &\qiq dM = Z^TdZ+dZ^TZ \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these variables
and an element-wise square root function
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= {\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \LR{Ze_k:Ze_k}^{1/2}} \\
 &= {\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \LR{e_ke_k^T:Z^TZ}^{1/2}} \\
 &= \frac 1n\LR{\sum_{k=1}^n e_ke_k^T}:\LR{Z^TZ}^{1/2} \\
 &= \frac 1n I:M^{1/2} \\
}$$
Then calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= \fracLR 1n I:\LR{\frac 12 M^{-1/2}\odot\c{dM}} \\
 &= \fracLR 1{2n}\Diag{M^{-1/2}}:\CLR{Z^TdZ+dZ^TZ} \\
 &= \fracLR 1{n}\Diag{M^{-1/2}}:\LR{Z^TdZ} \\
 &= \fracLR 1{n}Z\Diag{M^{-1/2}}:\c{dZ} \\
 &= \fracLR 1{n}Z\Diag{M^{-1/2}}:\c{\LR{-AEBX}\,d\a} \\
\grad{\phi}{\a}
 &= -\fracLR 1{n}Z\Diag{M^{-1/2}}:\LR{AEBX} \\
 &= -\fracLR 1{n}\trace{\Diag{M^{-1/2}}\,Z^TAEBX} \\
\\
}$$

---

In the above, $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product, while a colon denotes the matrix inner product,
which is a really concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in lots of different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
and it commutes with the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
A:\bR{B\odot C}
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}\,\BR{B_{ij}C_{ij}} \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \BR{A_{ij}B_{ij}}\,C_{ij} \\
 &= \bR{A\odot B}:C \\\\
}$$
Last but not least, don't forget that ${M}^{-1/2}\,$ is meant to be a scalar function applied elementwise
$\Big({\rm i.e.}\; M_{ij}^{-1/2}\Big)$
rather than the matrix inverse of $M^{1/2}\,$
and that `Diag()` sets all off-diagonal elements to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer @greg. I think that given steph's answer it should be that $dE = -B e^{-a B} da = -B E da$ ?

Comment: As a I wrote in ly answer, matrices commute so you can also write $dE=-EB da$

Answer (score 2):

Your computation is wrong since the gradient should be a scalar.
Using the same notations as Greg, you can simplify a bit the computations.

Denote the vector $\mathbf{z}_n=\mathbf{A}e^{-a\mathbf{B}}\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{y}_n$.
Doing so, the cost function writes
$
\phi(a) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_n \| \mathbf{z}_n \|_2
$

Taking the differential
$$
d\phi 
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_n  \frac{\mathbf{z}_n}{\|\mathbf{z}_n\|}:d\mathbf{z}_n
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_n  \frac{\mathbf{z}_n}{\|\mathbf{z}_n\|}:\mathbf{A}(de^{-a\mathbf{B}})\mathbf{x}_n
$$
Because
$de^{-a\mathbf{B}}=-\mathbf{B}e^{-a\mathbf{B}} da$ (note that the matrices commute), we end up with the gradient
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial a}
=
\frac{-1}{N} \sum_n  \frac{\mathbf{z}_n}{\|\mathbf{z}_n\|}:\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}e^{-a\mathbf{B}}\mathbf{x}_n
=
\frac{-1}{N} \mathrm{tr}
\left[ 
(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{D}_Z)^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}e^{-a\mathbf{B}}\mathbf{X}
\right]
$$
where $\mathbf{D}_Z$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $1/\|\mathbf{z}_n\|$ along its diagonal.

Comment: See my update for $\mathbf{D}_Z$

Answer (score 0):

I'd say 2 things have to be corrected. First there must be a minus sign coming from the minus sign in the exponent of the matrix exponential. Second a factor 2 in the denominator is missing, this one coming from the derivation of a square root (as is the 2-norm = euclidian norm)